# How can I make sure that my github action workflow is working as intended?

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I have a simple python script which classifies balls according to their type. The script is working as intended on my local machine.

How can I make sure that the git action workflow is running as well? I need to run the script every night. But for now I want to know if the workflow is even working.

This is my .yml file code:

```
name: Batch predictions

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '* * * * *' 

jobs:
  predict:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: check out repository content
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.9'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Execute py script
      run: python batch_predict.py
```

This is my github repo: https://github.com/kmeans27/ball-classification

Thank you for the help!

Comment: First you should get the syntax of your workflow right. Your first step is wrong. Each step has to have a `uses` or `run` key.

Comment: You can configure it for the `workflow_dispatch` event as well and run it manually for testing it. Also, see [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxdUc1KxDAQvucp5rYgpIKe7EkED94WfABJ08FG22TMTNYt+PAmacTtksuQ729+vFmwhycjdgKKODorLnhWKvheAbCdcEwzlhpAg435Hw430N4BlPoIAxe8yTdqTJ514aYheUl6NoIsFWJB4j9DX/Nziv2EkAQiUmAnIa5ggxf00oiJkXswW3u3VZD5j6c7tXN6RYFEcFxlCr4icCVllESaKqHIN863k6lvdR6lovqEkV0d+L57OOyDXjyLmWcYkdCP6K1Dbvo8ew8/V2agFyBH4JpO60Tv0YxYfv+5l4yYt/GVXMQlr4E7Ocu+hecz2iTZYM13io7kMr+lDuWyb+00Ha2/A+GXxg==) for the issues in your current workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The workflow is not running since you have a typo in your workflow file. On line 11:

   ```yaml
       - name: check out repository content
       - uses: actions/checkout@v2
   ```

   should be

   ```yaml
       - name: check out repository content
         uses: actions/checkout@v2
   ```

   You can check GitHub Actions output [here](https://github.com/kmeans27/ball-classification/actions/runs/4293138442)
2. In ubuntu, you should use `python3` instead of `python` to call your Python 3 environment.
3. You can add an `workflow_dispatch:` entry in `on`.

   ```yaml
   on:
     schedule:
       - cron: '* * * * *'
     workflow_dispatch:
   ```

   `workflow_dispatch:` event allows you to manually trigger a workflow execution.
4. If you do want to trace into execution of your Python script, consider add a few `print()` in your code or use `logging` standard library.